# Group by ID, separate the rest into different columns

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to create a table that looks like the following examples..

```
| SO_NUMBER | ORDER                      |
------------------------------------------
| 12345     | iphone5|1|500|APPLE        |
| 12345     | icase-blk|1|20|CaseCompany |
| 23411     | galaxy5|1|500|Samsung      |
| 23411     | galaxy-blk|1|20|CaseCompany|
```

Convert that to this..

```
| SO_NUMBER | ORDER_1                    | ORDER_2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 12345     | iphone5|1|500|APPLE        | icase-blk|1|20|CaseCompany
| 23411     | galaxy5|1|500|Samsung      | galaxy-blk|1|20|CaseCompany
```

I'm not sure where to start, I can group by the SO_Number fine, but not sure if I need to create a temporary table. I've search around and all I could find is grouping them together with commas but that won't work for this.

EDIT:
I've started looking at Option Compare Database RunningCount Script to do what i asked for. It works for the most part.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public wName As String
Public wRuningCount As Long
Function GetRunCount(Name1) As Long
If wName = Name1 Then
wRuningCount = wRuningCount + 1
Else
wName = Name1
wRuningCount = 1
End If
GetRunCount = wRuningCount
End Function
```

But now I get

```
| SO_NUMBER | ORDER_1 | ORDER_3 |
```

instead of

```
| SO_NUMBER | ORDER_1 | ORDER_2 |
```

The query the auto script setup is the following..

```
TRANSFORM First([123].ORDER) AS FirstOfORDER
SELECT [123].SO_NUMBER
FROM 123
GROUP BY [123].SO_NUMBER
PIVOT [123].GetRunCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Query Wizard and create a crosstab query. Below is a sample:

```
TRANSFORM First([Tbl1].[SO_NUMBER]) AS FirstOftype
SELECT [Tbl1].[SO_NUMBER]
FROM Tbl1
GROUP BY [Tbl1].[SO_NUMBER]
PIVOT [Tbl1].[Order];
```

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work. It gives me the error too many columns. When closer inspecting it doing a where by 5 days. It shows me that it's trying to list the product themselves as the columns and the rows by the so number.

Comment: What is the max number of unique values that you have for an 'so_number'? If more than 255, you're out of luck. If less than, did you try the query wizard or did you just use my sample?

Comment: Both, I get the same error too many columns. Wondering if I should create a table with just order_1,order_2,order_3,order_4,order_5  in it. Then slap that in as a header. Maybe I can trick it..

Comment: How many unique values??? When you run the query, if it fails, it will show the total number in (). If more than 255 - you need a new plan.

Comment: Rows wise, way more than 255. Columns wise, maybe 10-100. Depends on how many items they order.